# "The import org cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

```
package FirstPackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class FirstClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\Users\\Udhayakumar\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.22.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe"); 
        WebDriver driver   =   new FirefoxDriverProvider();

    }

}
```

JDK 10.0.2
Selenium JAR: 3.14.0
Selenium Standalne JAR 3.14.0
Eclipse Photon

Comment: The same issue occurs even if FirefoxDriver is used instead FirefoxDriverProvider

Comment: You have to configure your workspace in order to use selenium. Check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xaWLIBKAQps

Comment: @Michael I have made the configurations mentioned  in the Youtube Video

Comment: try  to clean the project , before running it

Comment: I found a workaround .Uninstall JDK 10.0.2 and Installed JDK 8U181     and the error is gone.